In Smart bear floating license, how to know the license is available for user before InstallTestCompleteAdapter task run?
In case of Smart bear  floating license, how to know the license is available for user before InstallTestCompleteAdapter task run?
i want to know whether the floating license is available or not for user, before running tests. How to do it?

i got the answer, thanks to smartbear support team.
The ans. is in Testexecute behavior, the Testexecute application check on license availability before getting start, if license is available in the pool then only Testexecute application will open.
Hence in loop i kept running below command, until testexecute open:
Start-Process -FilePath $testExecutePath -ArgumentList "/SilentMode /Exit /AccessKey:$AccessKey" -PassThru -Wait
